# Indentation appearing out of nowhere

Tags: indentation, alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=2.54cm,
        right=2.54cm,
        top=2.54cm,
        bottom=2.54cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}

%% Useful packages
%\usepackage{hyperref} %for linking stuff within the document 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{optidef}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
  
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=2pt}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}

\title{\vspace{-1.5cm}\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont\textbf{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention as a Strategic Agent in the Pediatric Vaccine Market: An Analytical Approach}}
\date{}
\author{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \textbf{abc rockets}} 

\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\citet{ref1} developed a vaccine pricing strategy, keeping the CDC as a potential player to stabilize the market and to keep the public sector prices as low as possible to \textbf {reduce the risk of a monopoly formation}. The risk of having a market with only one manufacturer is established in Table 1. We observe that the pricing dynamics shifts when market has one, two, or three manufacturers using examples of prices (in price in USD/ dosage) of Varicella, Hepatitis B (Hep B), and Haemophilus influenza type b (Hib) from 2010 to 2020. 

\begin{table}[ht]\small 
\caption{Pediatric Vaccine Markets} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular} {c c c c }
\hline 
Year & Varicella(monopoly) & Hep B (duopoly) & HiB(triopoly)\\
\hline
2010 & \$64.53 & \$9.88 & \$ 9.54 \\
2020 & \$109.26 & \$18.96 & \$10.91\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} We see that the monopoly market has highest price increase followed by a duopoly market and triopoly market. Thus, the pediatric vaccine market will have the lowest cost of vaccines when there are more manufacturers. Following \citet{ref1}, we studied pediatric vaccine market through a case study on the DTaP vaccine market in the United States.\\ Competitive DTaP vaccine market is dominated by two manufactures: GSK and Sanofi Pasteur which produce Infanrix and Daptacel respectively. The vaccines are considered to be competitive if they are produced according to the US Routine Immunization Schedule (RIS)

\end{document}
```

I don't know why there is small spacing that appears after the table has ended. I am trying to remove it but it is just not working..

Comment: is it not possible to correct it?

Comment: where ? exactly... as you can tell I have bare minimum knowledge of latex..

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to "correct" it? It _is_ a new paragraph and using `\noindent` just confuses the reader by hiding that. (or if it is not a new paragraph do not leave a blank line that ended the previous paragraph.

Comment: Oh so.. I thought it was making the document not aligned properly.

Comment: It is your text, you can decide if it is a new paragraph or not, but if it is a new paragraph and all the other paragraphs in the document are indented than indent this one too. You should almost never need `\noindent`. If it isn't a new paragraph don't put a blank line in the source after the previous text.

Comment: @campa I didn't intend you to delete, that may be the preferred answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The explanation was indeed misleading but I have no time now to rewrite it, so I rather delete than leaving public something bad...

Comment: @campa OK, fair enough:-)

Comment: I think you both are equally right. I am sorry, my academic writing abilities are non existing. Thank you to both of you :)

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Comment: If the answer do not fully answer the question then leave a comment below the answers and not just do nothing. Otherwise it is impossible to close a topic.

Answer (score 7):

The indentation is not "out of nowhere" you explicitly ended the previous paragraph with a blank line after "2020." so the following text is a new paragraph, so indented.
If you delete the blank line then the following text is part of the same paragraph.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=2.54cm,
        right=2.54cm,
        top=2.54cm,
        bottom=2.54cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}

%% Useful packages
%\usepackage{hyperref} %for linking stuff within the document 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{optidef}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
  
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=2pt}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}

\title{\vspace{-1.5cm}\fontsize{15}{20}\selectfont\textbf{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention as a Strategic Agent in the Pediatric Vaccine Market: An Analytical Approach}}
\date{}
\author{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont \textbf{abc rockets}} 

\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\citet{ref1} developed a vaccine pricing strategy, keeping the CDC as a potential player to stabilize the market and to keep the public sector prices as low as possible to \textbf {reduce the risk of a monopoly formation}. The risk of having a market with only one manufacturer is established in Table 1. We observe that the pricing dynamics shifts when market has one, two, or three manufacturers using examples of prices (in price in USD/ dosage) of Varicella, Hepatitis B (Hep B), and Haemophilus influenza type b (Hib) from 2010 to 2020. 
\begin{table}[ht]\small 
\caption{Pediatric Vaccine Markets} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular} {c c c c }
\hline 
Year & Varicella(monopoly) & Hep B (duopoly) & HiB(triopoly)\\
\hline
2010 & \$64.53 & \$9.88 & \$ 9.54 \\
2020 & \$109.26 & \$18.96 & \$10.91\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} We see that the monopoly market has highest price increase followed by a duopoly market and triopoly market. Thus, the pediatric vaccine market will have the lowest cost of vaccines when there are more manufacturers. Following \citet{ref1}, we studied pediatric vaccine market through a case study on the DTaP vaccine market in the United States.\\ Competitive DTaP vaccine market is dominated by two manufactures: GSK and Sanofi Pasteur which produce Infanrix and Daptacel respectively. The vaccines are considered to be competitive if they are produced according to the US Routine Immunization Schedule (RIS)

\end{document}
```

[image]